# bash LS command giving hidden folders in output

Tags: bash, terminal

I am not sure when this behavior started but by typing the `ls` command, I am getting the following output:

```
$ls
./         ../        .DS_Store  Books/
```

I am not very sure about the first three items and they always come in every folder. Can anyone explain me how to get rid of them? I am using OS X Yosemite

Comment: Maybe you have an alias?

Comment: your `ls` is `alias`ed to `ls -a`. Enter `type ls` to verify.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Just checked my bash_profile. It is aliased. I think my friend did it sometime back. I had removed it. Thanks.

Comment: @anishsane It is aliased! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two: `./` and `../` are *current* directory and *parent* directory respectively. You can't get rid of them. The last one `.DS_Store` is probably some config file/directory which you can remove with:

```
rm -f .DS_Store # use -r if it's a directory
```

But be sure to check what's its for!

The bahaviour of `ls` is not the reason for the "extra" output. You probably have an alias something like:

```
alias ls='ls -a'
```

in your shell. To find out exactly what it's aliased to, do:

```
type ls
```